# javascript array function can't be used

Tags: javascript, node.js

below is a piece of js code.When I run it with "node" command. It displays. "notes.filter" is not a function.If I comment "JSON.parse" line. It works. But video tutorial does have this line. So I am quite confused here.  Could any one helps here. Thanks a lot.

```
var addNote = (title, body) => {
  var notes = [];
  var note = {
    title,
    body
  }

  try {
    var notesstring = fs.readFileSync('notes-data.json');
    notes = JSON.parse(notesstring);
  } catch (e) {

  }

  console.log(Array.isArray(notes));
  var duplicateNote = notes.filter((note) => note.title === title);
  if (duplicateNote.length === 0) {
    notes.push(note);
    fs.writeFileSync('notes-data.json', JSON.stringify(note));
  }
};
```

Comment: What's the output of `node --version` if you run it from the command line?

Comment: What is the content of `notes-data.json`? What is the output of `console.log(Array.isArray(notes));` in the case where you use `JSON.parse()`? If you comment the `JSON.parse()` line then the `notes` variable stays as the empty array it was originally assigned.

Comment: @nnnnnn Content is probably whatever has been put there using this function on the line fs.writeFileSync...

Comment: You're writing out a single note, but then trying to read in an array. What are you trying to do? Do you want to write out the array with the additional new element? Then do that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while going through the course but ended up fixing it.

For some reason, I was getting back bad JSON, and so I had to delete the note-data.json file, and then re-run the app. This fixed it for me!

Comment: Welcome to SO! To improve your answer you could investigate why deleting the notes-data.json file is required and possibly provide the new code where it runs without having to perform that manual step. Also in your answer you state "note-data.json" whereas the question mentions "notes-data.json".